# Firebase: FieldValue.arrayUnion with objects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example I have a doc like this:

```
team: {
members: [{name: "john", age: 2}, {name: "tim", age: 3}]
}
```

And I want to update Tims age to 4 `{name: "tim", age: 3}` to `{name: "tim", age: 4}`

Can I do this using **FieldValue.arrayUnion** ?

Because right now.

```
...
.update({team: firbase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({name: "tim", age: 4})})
```

Will create new entry and team will be like

```
[
 {name: "john", age: 2}, 
 {name: "tim", age: 3}, 
 {name: "tim", age: 4} <-- duplicate
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, arrayUnion will not work here.  arrayUnion considers each item in the list to be unique based on its **entire** contents. Two objects are not considered the same unless **all** of their properties are strictly equal.  That's why you're getting a whole new item in the list - the ages are not the same, and Firestore has no way of knowing that you only want "name" to be unique.

If you want to alter the contents of an array, you will have to read the document, change the contents of the array in memory, then write the altered contents back to the document.  A [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) may be appropriate for this.

One other thought: consider storing ages in terms of birth dates instead of current ages.  Birth dates never change, and ages can be computed based on the the current time relate to birth date.

Comment: So the way to solve this would be to remove the first Tim (age 3) using arrayRemove and then arrayUnion the new one?